# Performing Dijkstra on gpx file

Tags: matlab, dijkstra, gpx

I have multiple gpx files from walking routes which I combined to one big gpx file so it displays a collection of all the routes of a certain area. I want to use the file in MATLAB and perform Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm on it. Can anyone recommend a way to do this?

Should I convert the gpx data in order to make it possible, or are there ways to make these calculations on the data itself?

Answer (score 1):

Recent MATLAB version has functions to read GPX files
https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/gpxread.html

and the File Exchange has few contributions for Dijkstra's Shortest Path Algorithm

Joseph Kirk (2021). Dijkstra's Shortest Path Algorithm https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12850-dijkstra-s-shortest-path-algorithm and Another here https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36140-dijkstra-algorithm